# pgSQL show an error in its function before the SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addData (x INT,y INT)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE temp(id,name,pass) VALUES(y,"ABC","XYZ");
END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

but the output is

> $$ LANGUAGE SQL
>   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
>   LINE 4: INSERT INTO TABLE temp(id,name,pass)

I tried by changing data type, double quotes to single quotes, please help me with this. I am currently using pSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT INTO TABLE...` no need `TABLE` keyword

`VALUES(y,"ABC","XYZ")...` You need single quotes instead of double

Since you use `BEGIN..END`, you need `plpgsql` language

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addData (x INT,y INT)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO temp(id,name,pass) VALUES(y,'ABC','XYZ');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgSQL;
```